# Newsstand magazine downloads very slow and halting

Tags: ios, newsstand

My newsstand has two subscriptions: New Yorker and Economist.

1. When a new issue is available for **either** one of those, the period required to download the issue is super slow, and unreliable - it will seem to spin along well, showing the download numbers increase, but then simply halt. The iPad will then go to its lock screen, and when I go back, zero additional downloading will have progressed in the meantime. In fact, sometimes it pops **back** to the previous downloaded amount prior to the last little progress session.
2. I have "download automatically" set in the preferences for Newsstand for these subscriptions. It doesn't do it on its own (and, as above, barely does it when I ask it to specifically).

Note:

- Yes, I have done the "show the currently running apps and then fully close down the NYer and Newssstand apps all the way" method - does not help… and I've shut down the iPad all the way and restarted, also.
- I live in Thailand, but I'm on a pretty fast DSL and the Wi-Fi is fine… jeez, in these times, overseas location doesn't matter, right?

Anyone have these problems **or** have a guess?

<sup>The iPad is the iPad 3, has the newest iOS as of today (Nov 2012), etc…</sup>

Comment: I'm not sure if this is applicable for Newsstand downloads, but in these days location still matters a lot, unless content is transparently distributed on localized servers.

Answer (score 1):

Your location doesn't matter, what matters is having a connection to the Apple service. Somewhere down the line something is getting messed up, below are the steps that I'll take to troubleshoot.

1. Reset networking settings on the iPad
2. Within the iPad try pinging a few domain names that Apple controls: "itunes.apple.com" is one of them.
3. Reset modem and reconfigure everything.

Answer (score 1):

The actual content of magazines and applications (rather than the store) is delivered via a Content Delivery Network (CDN) that relies on knowing where you are.

This can get upset and give you content from a server a long way from you under certain circumstances.

To check this out first visit http://whatismyipaddress.com/ or some such which will translate your IP address back to a location.

Second, the CDN uses DNS trickery to send you to the nearest server so make sure you are using the DNS recommended by your ISP.

This may fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a vpn turn it off. I did and it fixed the slow download problem